# Splitting a file on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, split, csplit

I have an 8.8G file on the hadoop cluster that I'm trying to extract certain lines for testing purpose.

Seeing that  [Apache Hadoop 2.6.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html) have no split command, how am I able to do it without having to download the file.

If the file was on a linux server I would've used:

```
$ csplit filename %2015-07-17%
```

The previous command works as desired, is something close to that possible on Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of unix and hdfs commands.

```
hadoop fs -cat filename.dat | head -250 > /redirect/filename
```

Or if last KB of the file is suffice you could use this.

```
hadoop fs -tail filename.dat > /redirect/filename
```

Comment: Not even realistic, there's about 54M lines in that file and the data I'm extracting is nowhere near `head -250`

Comment: HDFS doesn't give you much command line features to work out. If you want to explore that then this could be the way unless and until you bring the file to local. Else a pig(with LIMIT) or MR script would do the need for you.

Comment: I'll just transfer to local since it's only one file. If I had multiple files then MR would be worth it. Thank you.

Comment: But still 8.8G file needs to be transferred. You could try writing a simple PIG script. A = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage as line; B = LIMIT your_number; C = STORE B INTO 'filename' ;